# Rails assert_routing on root route raises ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I'm trying to test that requesting the root path (`/`) routes to my beta controller's `:new` action. When I do this manually (in my browser), it works fine. But my automated test is failing with `No route matches "/"`.

In `config/routes.rb` I have

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'beta#new' # Previously: `redirect('/beta/join')`
end
```

In my `spec/routing/root_route_spec.rb` I have tried

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "the root route" do
  it "should route to beta signups" do
    get('/').should route_to(controller: :beta, action: :new)
  end
end
```

and have also tried

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "the root route" do
  it "should route to beta signups" do
    assert_routing({ method: :get, path: '/' }, { controller: :beta, action: :new })                                                                                                                                     
  end
end
```

but both complain that `No route matches "/"`

```
1) the root route should route to the beta signups
   Failure/Error: get('/').should route_to "beta#new"
     No route matches "/"
   # ./spec/routing/root_route_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I go, in my browser, to `localhost:3000`, I'm correctly routed to the `BetaController::new` action.

What explains the `No route matches "/"` error?

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and RSpec-2.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test that `/` redirects to `/beta/join` and then as a separate issue test that `/beta/join` routes to the `:new` action of the `:beta` controller.

Redirection is tested in `requests`, not `routing`.

```
# spec/requests/foobar_spec.rb
describe 'root' do
  it "redirects to /beta/join" do
    get "/"
    response.should redirect_to("/beta/join");
  end
end
```

and

```
# spec/routing/beta_spec.rb
...
it 'routes /beta/join to the new action'
  get('beta/join').should route_to(:controller => 'beta', :action => 'new')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. This is a reasonable way to test my application, and it resolves the errors. However, I'm searching for an explanation of the 'No route matches "/"' error. I've updated my question to be more specific - hope you can help!